# Теги html при выводе текста из базы данных

Tags: python, html, django, ckeditor, jinja2

*Проблема при выводе из* `TextField` *данных модели в* `html` *шаблон*.
Я использую библиотеку `ckeditor` для встроенного редактора на своём сайте при создании поста, но при выводе текста из базы данных выводятся теги `html` служащие для форматирования текста:
[image: редактор в админке]

[image: вывод информации в шаблоне]

в шаблоне текст выводится через `{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}`

Answer (score 2):

не правильно выводите на страницу. Вместо `{{post.text|linebreaksbr}}` используйте `{{post.text|safe}}`